# What is a proper test of significance for large distributions with long tails?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, statistical-significance, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, permutation-test

I want to see if two distributions I have are significantly different or not. They have long tails but their log-transforms are close to being normal. The number of samples is usually large, anything from a few thousands to hundreds of thousands. Therefore Student's t-test is not appropriate to use.

The only tests I know that *may* be useful for such a situation are the permutation test and the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test however **I don't know if these two tests are subject to any form of bias in my particular case or if there are other more suitable tests.** I've also tried the z-test for the log transform of the distributions but it seems the difference between the two distributions diminishes quite a lot after taking the log-transform.

Comment: Since the Student t test does not compare distributions--it only compares their means--it isn't clear what you're actually trying to do.  It's essential to know that if we are to understand what you might mean by "bias."  Are you interested only in means or are you interested in the entire distribution?

Comment: That's a good question. I'm interested in the entire distribution and/however ultimately am looking for a discriminant (as in discriminant analysis). By bias I mostly meant type I & II errors such as what you get in a t-test with a large sample.